# Indexing decimal values in zope catalog

Tags: plone, zope

I'm using Plone 4.2.5 and dexterity

I have added a field to a custom content type and would like to index one of the fields. It's a decimal field. Preferrably I'd like to be able to query the catalog using 'greater than' or 'less than or equal to' type logic for the index. Is this possible? What type of index should I use?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `FieldIndex` for your field. You can do range searches on field indexes using the [`range` keyword](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/SearchingZCatalog.html#fieldindex-record-attributes):

```
catalog(indexname=dict(query=10.5, range='max'))
```

would return matches for which the index `indexname` value is 10.5 or less. For a strict `less than`, subtract [`sys.float_info.epsilon`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) to the query value:

```
catalog(indexname=dict(query=10.5, range='max'))                          # less than or equal to
catalog(indexname=dict(query=10.5 - sys.float_info.epsilon, range='max')) # less than
```